# Unable to launch Appium from Jenkins

Tags: android, windows, jenkins, appium

Im trying to launch my Appium tests from Jenkins. It’s working great when i:

- Starting Appium server manually (cmd.exe Appium)
- Launch tests from
  Jenkins.

but when i try to add new step and launch Appium server from Jenkins by using this command:

```
call node C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js --address 0.0.0.0 --port 4723 --no-reset
```

Jenkins console returns:

> [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

and nothing happens. Tests doesnt working. No any errors…just nothing happens.

Can you help me?

Thanks

P.S. Win 7 (64 bit), Appium server 1.7.1 (installed via npm)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to start Appium server [programatically](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/service/local/ServerBuilderTest.java):

```
import static io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService

AppiumDriverLocalService service = 
AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
    service.start();
    assertEquals(true, service.isRunning());
```

Comment: i tried this way. it's working perfectrly in IDE but doesnt work in Jenkins when i run Gradle Task. Second: when i launch Appium from Jenkins it's easy to change listener ip and port.

Comment: Do you run your tests and Appium server on the same machine? If yes, then programmatic way should work perfectly. If no, then make sure you can access Appium service from the machine where you run tests:  use ip address and port, e.g. in browser http://<ip>:<port>/wd/hub/session and then check logs for appium server on the machine where its its running

Comment: I can't open http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/session. Where i can find Appium logs? I'm running tests on same PC

Comment: from logs: 2017-11-21 07:38:25:294 - info: [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.7.1
2017-11-21 07:38:25:378 - info: [Appium] Non-default server args:
2017-11-21 07:38:25:378 - info: [Appium]   sessionOverride: true
2017-11-21 07:38:25:379 - info: [Appium]   log: C:\appium\appium.log
2017-11-21 07:38:25:448 - info: [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

Comment: If you are running server and tests on the same machine, the best way is to start/stop server programatically. My initial post contains details. How do you start tests in jenkins?

Comment: i can't run tests programatically. I'm getting error:  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Provide your test code and the way you launch them, `mvn clean test`

Comment: im using Gradle (not Maven). My Gradle task (Invoke Gradle script): clean test --tests $Test. Now i can launch Appium and Test from IDE but still can't launch from Jenkins (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        Caused by: io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException
            Caused by: java.io.IOException)

Comment: may be it's because my test class (where my tests) extends class that contains setUp() method (with DesiredCapabilities)? But why it's working in IDE?

Comment: there is nothing to say without code snippet you are using and full stacktrace + appium server log (if there is any)